# filtering data when the next value in a Time-series is bigger

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to subset a data frame like below :-

If the entries in "time_col" column of a dataframe are as follows:

```
# 00:00:00, 00:10:00,16:14:00, 22:59:00, 01:00:00, 04:14:00, 08:18:00, 18:18:00
```

then we need to create 2 data frames becuase the times above represent
2 different days.

```
# data_frame_1 -> 00:00:00, 00:10:00,16:14:00, 22:59:00
# data_frame_2 -> 01:00:00, 04:14:00, 08:18:00, 18:18:00
```

I am having a timeseries Data and the time which is in sequence but after the time 23:59:00 its again starting from 00:00:00 but that is for the next day.

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

In simple words if a column in a df is having value like below and lowest & highest values are 0 and 9:-

```
#1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,4,5,8
```

So, I want to filter the df into below multiple dataframes like :-

```
#df1<- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
#df2<- 4,5,6,7,8
#df3<- 1,2,4,5,8
```

I want to make this dynamic.I mean if there are 3 days or 30 days, it should work in both the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `df`:

```
       times
0   00:00:00
1   00:10:00
2   16:14:00
3   22:59:00
4   01:00:00
5   04:14:00
6   08:18:00
7   18:18:00
```

You can do it in 2 steps as below:

```
df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(df.times)
df['group_label'] = df.groupby(df.times.diff().dt.days.cumsum().fillna(0)).grouper.group_info[0]
df['times'] = df.times.dt.time
list_dfs = [df.loc[df.group_label==x].drop('group_label',1) for x in df.group_label.unique()]
```

Output:

```
 [0    00:00:00
 1    00:10:00
 2    16:14:00
 3    22:59:00
 Name: times, dtype: object, 
 4    01:00:00
 5    04:14:00
 6    08:18:00
 7    18:18:00
 Name: times, dtype: object]
```

You can access the list as

`list_dfs[0]`

```
    times
0   00:00:00
1   00:10:00
2   16:14:00
3   22:59:00
```

`list_dfs[1]`

```
    times
4   01:00:00
5   04:14:00
6   08:18:00
7   18:18:00
```

Comment: I am gettig exactly the same output what you have posted but how to also get the corresponding values of each timestamp and finally creating different dataframes

Comment: `list_dfs` is a `list` of dataframes. It has all the sub dataframes. if you do `list_dfs[0]`, you will have first sub dataframe and so on. @ak333

Comment: man....you are a champ :) that work like a charm. You saved my day today.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,4,5,8])
s.groupby(s.diff().lt(0).cumsum()).apply(list)
Out[115]: 
0    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1                [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
2                [1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but in my condition thats a column of a dataframe and I want to filter the dataframe and create multiple dataframes based on this condition.

Comment: `{x: y for x, y in df.groupby(df.date.diff().lt(0).cumsum()}` @ak333

Comment: I am getting this error."cannot compare a TimedeltaIndex with type int".   IF I can perform the same thing on string then that would also help me.  I am a beginner so sorry for lots of question.@wen

Comment: @ak333 convert to datetime first

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

@wen

Comment: It worked out Wen. Thanks a lot for giving your time.